# GDI+ Error only occuring on windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, gdi+

I have some c# code that works fine on Vista & Windows 7 but throws a GDI+ Error on Windows XP (with service pack 3 installed).

Error thrown on XP

> System.Runtime.INteropServices.ExternalException(0x80004005): A generic error occured in GDI+
>   at System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32Status)
>   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Int32 x, Int32 y)
>   At System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(Image image, Int32 x,Int 32 y)
>   at mysolution.Core.ImageTools.ConvertToBitonal(Bitmap orginal, Int32 threshold)

Code breaks on this line:

```
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(source))
   {
      g.DrawImageUnscaled(original, 0, 0); // Error Is Thrown Here
   }
```

WpFAppTestingConvertToBitonalCS

....

Below is the full function I'm calling.

```
    public static Bitmap ConvertToBitonal(Bitmap original, int threshold)
    {
        Bitmap source;

        // If original bitmap is not already in 32 BPP, ARGB format, then convert
        if (original.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        {
            source = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            source.SetResolution(original.HorizontalResolution, original.VerticalResolution);

            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(source))
            {
                g.DrawImageUnscaled(original, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            source = original;
        }

        // Lock source bitmap in memory
        var sourceData = source.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        // Copy image data to binary array
        var imageSize = sourceData.Stride * sourceData.Height;
        var sourceBuffer = new byte[imageSize];
        Marshal.Copy(sourceData.Scan0, sourceBuffer, 0, imageSize);

        // Unlock source bitmap
        source.UnlockBits(sourceData);

        // Create destination bitmap
        var destination = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
        destination.SetResolution(original.HorizontalResolution, original.VerticalResolution);

        // Lock destination bitmap in memory
        var destinationData = destination.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, destination.Width, destination.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);

        // Create destination buffer
        imageSize = destinationData.Stride * destinationData.Height;
        var destinationBuffer = new byte[imageSize];

        var sourceIndex = 0;
        var destinationIndex = 0;
        var pixelTotal = 0;
        byte destinationValue = 0;
        var pixelValue = 128;
        var height = source.Height;
        var width = source.Width;

        // Iterate lines
        for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            sourceIndex = y * sourceData.Stride;
            destinationIndex = y * destinationData.Stride;
            destinationValue = 0;
            pixelValue = 128;

            // Iterate pixels
            for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                // Compute pixel brightness (i.e. total of Red, Green, and Blue values) - Thanks murx
                //                           B                             G                              R
                pixelTotal = sourceBuffer[sourceIndex] + sourceBuffer[sourceIndex + 1] + sourceBuffer[sourceIndex + 2];
                if (pixelTotal > threshold)
                {
                    destinationValue += (byte)pixelValue;
                }
                if (pixelValue == 1)
                {
                    destinationBuffer[destinationIndex] = destinationValue;
                    destinationIndex++;
                    destinationValue = 0;
                    pixelValue = 128;
                }
                else
                {
                    pixelValue >>= 1;
                }
                sourceIndex += 4;
            }

            if (pixelValue != 128)
            {
                destinationBuffer[destinationIndex] = destinationValue;
            }
        }

        // Copy binary image data to destination bitmap
        Marshal.Copy(destinationBuffer, 0, destinationData.Scan0, imageSize);

        // Unlock destination bitmap
        destination.UnlockBits(destinationData);

        // Dispose of source if not originally supplied bitmap
        if (source != original)
        {
            source.Dispose();
        }

        // Return
        return destination;
    }
```

Comment: You posted one hundred of lines: where the exception is actually raised?

Comment: We aren't sure at the moment which line it is on, I will check that out on Monday, by putting additional logging in and testing on an xp machine.

Comment: @Mario Vernari it breaks on this line: using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(source))
{
g.DrawImageUnscaled(original, 0, 0);
}

Comment: General question: is your XP allready on SP3? I had some .Net code malfunctioning under SP2 that run without a hitch under SP3.

Comment: The XP machine is service pack 3, I've updated my question to include that information.

Comment: What is the bitmap format of `original` when the error is thrown?

Comment: GDI+ was updated to v1.10 at Vista with much improved support for indexed pixel formats.

Comment: @Hans, anyway around this, as I can't get the version of windows updated on the PCs.

Comment: The only way that I know of to get around this is to use a third-party image format library for load/save/convert or write your own image handler code.  GDI+ in XP has a variety of image format limitations compared to the newer Os's, including less support for various TIF formats, JPG-compressed TIFs, certain indexed pixel formats, etc.  Which is why I was wondering what the `original` bitmap format was.  Perhaps SO guru Hans knows of some other workaround.

Comment: Just a thought: you could look into using `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` to see if it will handle the image file formats you require.

Comment: @deegee anyway we can do the convert to bitonal using system.windows.media.imaging, I'm not very familiar with that library?

Comment: @DermFrench : I'm actually just getting into using System.Windows.Media.Imaging myself recently, mainly for handling 16/48/64bpp image formats, so I can't offer any definitive answer to your question at this time.  I will know more about it over the next few weeks.

Comment: Its been a few weeks since, but in case you are still looking for solutions then take a look at this kb (CAUSE: This issue occurs because the improved GDI+ in XP provides less support to read TIFF files compressed in JPEG): http://support.microsoft.com/?id=885938

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown on that line?I had a similar  issue,but it was not related to the line you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I hate GDI+ exception handling, the only error it fires is  A generic error occured in GDI+, Try this

```
Bitmap source = new Bitmap(0, 0);  
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(source))  
{   g.Clear(Color.White); 
    g.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(your original source,0,0);  
}
```